# How to scan inactive/delisted stocks using Auto Analysis in Amibroker?

Tags: stocks, stockquotes

I would like to know all stock symbols that are no longer being traded for the last 1 year. How can I do this using AFL code via Amibroker's Auto Analysis/Scan tool?

Answer (score 0):

Explore on 1 recent bar:

Gap=252;
Filter=Now(3)-DateNum()>=Gap;